# Does firestore pull only document changes everytime we restart the app?

Tags: android, ios, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have some queries regarding how the pricing work and the internal structure of firestore sdk.

1. Consider this scenario I am using flutter and if i am running this method `firestore.collection('collection_name').get().docs` every time i open the app. Lets say i have a 1000 documents in this collection.
   Will i be charged for 1000 reads every time I open the app or will firestore read only the documents that has changed?
   The question is that "Is firestore smart enough to get only the documents that are changed" or will it fetch all the 1000 documents every time I REOPEN my flutter app.
2. In `firestore.collection('collection_name').get().docs`
   in this is it the `get()` part or the docs part that actually fetch the documents from firestore via network.
3. Ive noticed a `firestore.collection().docChanges`
   what is docChanges for can i use it to get only the changed documents from firestore or does it fetch all documents from firestore and returns only the changed ones.

What I observed (i have not done this test intensively maybe i have overlooked something):
Iam using the flutterfire extension for flutter to use firestore.I ran some tests although there is a chance something has escaped my tests. What i did is that i went to Gcp console firestore section and compared the total reads after opening app without clearing the cache and with clearing the cache. New reads were shown only when i cleared the cache. Is the flutterfire plugin smart enough to do this or did i overlook something ?

Answer (score 2):

> Will i be charged for 1000 reads every time I open the app or will firestore read only the documents that has changed?

You will be charged every time the code of the query is executed, as long as there is a network connection to satisfy the query.  There will be no partially cached results.  If you want to specifically query **only** the cache, you will have to specify that out at the time of the query, and it will only return cached results.  You should pass a GetOptions parameter to [get()](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/Query/get.html) that specifies the query should use a cache source.

> what is docChanges for can i use it to get only the changed documents from firestore

[docChanges](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/QuerySnapshot/docChanges.html) is a property of QuerySnapshot.  It is only useful if you are using a listener on a query that receives changes to documents in real time.  It has no use with single result sets that from calls to `get()`, so it will not be helpful in the specific case here.

Comment: Hi, i have a question say i have a query "Firestore.instance.collection("xyz").where("a"=="b"); if i execute this, how many reads will it cost if, 1) thr are 2 documents whch has a=b 2) there are none. Kindly pardon me if it sounds stupid, I jst started learning firebase

Comment: If you have a new question, please post it separately.  Stack Overflow only allows one question per post, and you've already asked two here.

Comment: I'm not the one who posted the question ^^'

Comment: Are you sure Doug? Iam using the flutterfire extension for flutter to use firestore.I ran some tests although there is a chance something has escaped my tests. What i did is that i went to Gcp platform and comoared the total reads after opening app without clearing the cache and with clearing the cache. New reads were shown lnly when i cleared the cache. Is the flutterfire plugin smart enough to do this did i overlook something.

Comment: If you observed something that suggests otherwise, your question should probably explain what exactly that was.  If you don't have a repeatable observation, I don't really have anything to add.

Comment: sorry i just accidnetly hit enter before completing the comment now i have edited it

Comment: Sorry, that's not really enough information to know how to reproduce the issue.  The cache isn't used to satisfy a query unless you tell the query to do so, or the network is unavailable at the time of the query.  If you observe something different, you should file a bug report with Firebase support explaining how to reliably reproduce the problem.  I've written about the cache extensively in this blog, so everything I know is there: https://medium.com/firebase-developers/firestore-clients-to-cache-or-not-to-cache-or-both-8f66a239c329

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it pull all the documents from scratch, so every time you open the app it will fetch all the documents.
And that might be a problem if you using so much recyclerView.
Cause a collection of documents will all be fetched every time user open your app.